# Adding PDF attachment using tfpdf?

Tags: php, pdf

I use the tFPDF component (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) for PDF creation in my PHP tool since many years. I now want to add some simple XML attachment to the PDF (EN 16931 for eInvoicing). I already have the XML but I need to attach the file. Sadly, I can not find any attachment functions in tFPDF. So, maybe it does not support this.

Is there an easy way to add this to tFPDF? Or any other ideas for adding the XML? I'm on Linux, maybe I can add the XML to the PDF file using a comandline tool? But I would prefer a solution with PHP code.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, I thought it is okay to simply add the XML file (not for ZUGFeRD but UBL for Peppol/EN 16931). So I need to first convert my PDF to PDF/A-3 including embedding of some color profile and then I need to add the attachment using PS code? Wow, no wonder this standard is so hard to follow for companies. Also, I looked for commandline tools (free/commercial) and all is Windows only. So sad...

Comment: Thank you. Yes, both are cross platform. In the meantime I decided to attach the XML to the email instead. Seems compatible with Peppol standard. And I attach the XML also to the PDF (sadly not PDF-A1 because of stripped unicode font). I was successful using the FPDF extension from http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script95.php (which also worked for attaching files with tFPDF).